# Linq query add to my database c# ERROR

Tags: c#, linq

I need the idviagem from the table tbviagem to put in idviagem from tbpassageiro (it's FK on tbpassageiro) , but i need to get idviagem from idatxt. Text it's in DateTime format

```
using (checkinEntities1 db = new checkinEntities1())
{

    var sel = from tbviagem in db.tbviagem
                where tbviagem.dia == DateTime.Parse(idatxt.Text)
                select tbviagem.idviagem;

    tbpassageiro myviagem = new tbpassageiro
    {

        nome = nometxt.Text,
        cc = cctxt.Text,
        fotocc = data,
        idviagem = sel < ----Why cannot I use this "sel", it gives me error,
        i'm desesperated, i have to put "idviagem" from tbbiagem on "idviagem" in tbpassageiro ,I need to do a select from a textbox (idatxt.Text) and take the idviagem from idatxt.Text

    };

    db.tbpassageiro.Add(myviagem);
    db.SaveChanges();

}
```

RESOLVER THIS WAY : I need to convert my DataTime format and put the sel.First(); Thank you all

```
         DateTime mydatatime = Convert.ToDateTime(idatxt.Text);


        using (checkinEntities1 db = new checkinEntities1())
        {

            var sel = from tbviagem in db.tbviagem
                      where tbviagem.dia == mydatatime
                      select tbviagem.idviagem;


            tbpassageiro myviagem = new tbpassageiro
            {


                nome = nometxt.Text,
                cc = cctxt.Text,
                fotocc = data,
                idviagem = sel.First()


            };



            db.tbpassageiro.Add(myviagem);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Comment: What is the exact type of tbpassageiro.idviagem? What is the exact type of sel?

Comment: idviagem it is a int , the sel only keep the result of the "Select "

Comment: "Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable <int> to int?"

Comment: I think that cannot convert ... i knowm! But, doing the query, getting a int , where is needed the convertation? (I'm new user in LINQ) sorry

Comment: But my error is in  clause "where" to -.-'      LINQ to Entities does not recognize the 'System.DateTime Parse (System.String)' method, and this method can not be converted to a storage expression

Comment: That is a different issue @GuilhermeMonteiro. To solve that, use `var bob = DateTime.Parse(idatxt.Text);  var sel = from tbviagem in db.tbviagem
                where tbviagem.dia == bob
                select tbviagem.idviagem;`

Comment: DateTime mydatatime = Convert.ToDateTime(idatxt.Text);
            

            using (checkinEntities1 db = new checkinEntities1())
            {

                var sel = from tbviagem in db.tbviagem
                          where tbviagem.dia == mydatatime
                          select tbviagem.idviagem;                      RESOLVED ! THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mentions the type of db.tbviagem. Let's assume it is an object that implements `IQueryable<TSource>` (or at least `IEnumerable<TSource>`)

If you hadn't used the `var sel`, but gave it a proper type, you would probably written something like:

```
IQueryable<TSource> = from tbviagem in db.tbviagem
    where tbviagem.dia == DateTime.Parse(idatxt.Text)
    select tbviagem.idviagem;
```

Meaning: from all TSource objects in the sequence of TSource objects that is stored in db.tbviagem, take only those TSource objects that have a value in property dia equal to the parsed value of idatxt.Text. The result represents a **query** to a sequence of TSource objects.

Note: the result is neither a TSource object, nor a sequence of TSource objects, it is a query. The query is executed when `GetEnumerator()` is called, either directly or indirectly (using `foreach` / ToList / FirstOrDefault / ...).

You wrote that a `tbpassageiro.idviagem` is an object of type int. Of course an int is not an `IQueryable<TSource>`. And hence you can't assign it.

Even if `TSource` would be `int`, then `sel` would be `IQueryable<int>`, and of course that can't be converted to an int.

You should ask yourself: what do I want in tbpasageiro.idviagem. Use words to describe it! It would be something like:

> tbpassageiro.idviagem is the first item in the result of the query that is stored in sel.

(this is if TSource is int).

or:

> tbpassageir.idviagem is the number of elements in the result of the query.

If you had exactly described what you'd want in idviagem, you would have seen that you didn't want the query itself, but one of the values in the result of the query. As long as your query has not be performed (= as long as it is an `IQueryable<...>`) you can't assign it to an int.

**Solution:** Make sure the query is performed before you assign:

To perform the query you should use a LINQ function that does not return an IQueryable / IEnumerable, but one that returns `List<TSource>` / `TSource[]` / `one TSource element`/ etc. These are functions like ToList / ToArray / FirstOrDefault / ...

Apparently you only want to assign to an int. It would be a waste to first fetch a thousand elements in a complete list and then take only one element for your assignment, so make sure you get only the element of your query that you want:

```
tbpassageir.idviagem = sel
    .Select(selElement => selElement.intProperty) // needed if TSource is not int
    .Skip(4)                                      // if you want the fifth element
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Other possible functions: `LastOrDefault` / `Single` / `Count` / `Max`

Comment: I really understand the explanation , thank you so much, i'm new at LINQ , really thank you ! Can i ask you something more? I'm doing the clause "where" well? because de LINQ dont recognize the DateTime Formar ( on idatxt.Text is a DateFormat, and i want the idviagem from this Date!

Comment: If `dia` is a `DateTime`, then I would Parse `idaText` before the LINQ statement. This way you can see errors in the text before you actually execute the query. Besides, you will be certain that the Parse is performed only once. Consider reading [The standard LINQ operations](https://odetocode.com/articles/739.aspx)

Comment: Thank You so much Already resolved ! with    DateTime mydatatime = Convert.ToDateTime(idatxt.Text);
            

            using (checkinEntities1 db = new checkinEntities1())
            {

                var sel = from tbviagem in db.tbviagem
                          where tbviagem.dia == mydatatime
                          select tbviagem.idviagem;
THAAAANK YOU SO MUCH!